# how to post muilti parameters on reload jqgrid in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

In view i have a button to search when click, I want to reload data with new parammater.
Below is my script

```
      function SearchClick() {
        var byer = $('#cbbSearch').val();
        var start = $('#txtDate').val();
        var end = $("#txtEndDate").val();
        var search = $("#txtFind").val();
        myJqgrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { byer: byer, start: start, end: end, search: search } }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
```

my url on create Grid is:

```
url: '/UIControl/SearchList?byer=' + byer + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&search=' + search
```

But in Controller the value start, end, search always null, only byer value is true. I don't know why?
Below is my Controller

```
        public ActionResult SearchList(string byer = "---", string start = "", string end = "", string search = "")
    {
        List<StyleSearch> lisData = SearchStyle(byer, start, end, search);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the value is not coming as null from the view itself? Can you try adding `console.log(byer, start, end, search)` at the end of the `SearchClick` function to check that?

Comment: console.log(byer, start, end, search) at the end of the SearchClick is: ACE 2017/07/06 2017/06/28 dsgdgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first look your code snippet looks fine. Could be some other issue, try using browser developer console (Inspect Element) this might show you some javascript error (if any).

There is another way to post form data back to server which I have used in one of my web application and till date its working fine without any issue. Please give a try and see if this works out.

```
myJqgrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { 
    postData: {
            byer: function () {
                return $("#cbbSearch").val();
            },
            start: function () {
                return $("#txtDate").val();
            },
            end: function () {
                return $("#txtEndDate").val();
            },
            search: function () {
                return $("#txtFind").val();
            },
        },
}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

*Note: Since jQGrid is a free version there are many forks available on web like [Trirand](http://www.trirand.net/), [Gurrido](http://guriddo.net/) and by [Oleg](https://github.com/OlegKi). The one I have used if official version by Tony Tomov (Trirand).*

Comment: In case you some more help I'll share the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for help. but i put code like this:   byer: function () {
                return "1";
            },start: function () {
                return "2";
            },
            end: function () {
                return "3";
            },
            search: function () {
                return "4";
            } But on controller  the value null. I don't know why?